# Como passar um objeto dentro de um props?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou tentando mostrar o os atributos do objeto música dentro de um componente mas ele só renderiza a lista mas não os atributos do objeto que eu passei. O que estou fazendo errado?

Objeto Musica:

```
function Music (banda, url, musica) {
   this.banda = banda;
   this.url = url;
   this.musica = musica;
}
```

Componente pra mostrar a música:

```
class Musica extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
        <li>
            <strong>{this.props.banda} </strong>
            <a href={this.props.url} target="_blank"> {this.props.musica} </a>
        </li>
        )
    }
}
```

Componente para montar a lista com as músicas:

```
    const music1 = new Music("Foster the people", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GMQLjzVGfw", "Houdini")
    const music2 = new Music("The Strokes", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pT68FS3YbQ4", "You Only Live Once")


class Musicas extends React.Component {    
    render () {
        return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <Musica props={music1}/>
                <Musica props={music2}/>
            </ul> 
        </div>   
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: no componente Musica, tente usar o spread operator para passar a props, ficaria assim "{...music1}", assim você terá acesso a cada propriedade individualmente. Do jeito que está hoje, provavelmente você só conseguirá acessar a propriedade dessa forma: "{this.props.music1.banda}" e assim em diante. Caso vc utilize o spread operator para passar as props, não será necessário fazer alteração no código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No componente `Musicas`, você deve definir uma outra chave que não `props` ou fazer o *spread* de todas as propriedades do objeto `Music`.

Deixo abaixo duas possíveis alternativas. Escolha aquela que parecer mais simples. :)

#### Alternativa 1: Passando uma `prop` `music`:

Uma alternativa é fazer assim:

```js
class Musicas extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <Musica music={music1} />
          <Musica music={music2} />
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

E no componente `Musica`:

```js
class Musica extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { banda, url, musica } = this.props.music;

    return (
      <li>
        <strong>{banda} </strong>
        <a href={url} target="_blank">
          {musica}
        </a>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Alternativa 2: Fazendo o *spread* das propriedades do objeto `Music`

Você pode utilizar o [*spread operator* (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) para passar todas as propriedades do objeto `Music` para o componente `Musica`:

```js
class Musicas extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <Musica {...music1} />
          <Musica {...music2} />
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

E no componente `Musica`, basta fazer da forma como você já usava anteriormente:

```js
class Musica extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <strong>{this.props.banda} </strong>
        <a href={this.props.url} target="_blank">
          {this.props.musica}
        </a>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

## Leitura recomendada:

- [Componentes e Props (Documentação Oficial do React)](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html);
- [Operador *spread* (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 1):

O erro está no "objeto" Música, na verdade você não criou um objeto, mas sim uma função que não está retornando nada.

O correto seria:

`function music (banda, url, musica) {
   return {
        banda: banda,
        url: url,
        musica: musica
   }
}`

Para criar uma das constantes seria:

`const music1 = music("Foster the people", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GMQLjzVGfw", "Houdini");`

E para passar:

`<Musica {...music1} />`

Comment: Eu mantive do outro jeito e está funcionando. Seria um jeito diferente de criar um objeto?

Comment: Se funcionou está ótimo. Sim seria uma syntax diferente